# yum update-> Error: Package on red hat Enterprise linux 7.9

Tags: rhel, software-installation, yum

On test host, red hat enterprise 7.9 after yum update i have Error Package. Can you help to forward Output yum update;

````
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Removing: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Updated By: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-49.el7_9.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-49.el7_9.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-18.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-18.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-20.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-20.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-20.el7_1.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-20.el7_1.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-24.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7_2.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_2.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7_3.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_3.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-28.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-28.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-28.el7_4.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-28.el7_4.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-32.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-32.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-33.el7_5.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-33.el7_5.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-37.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-37.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-38.el7_6.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-38.el7_6.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-43.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-43.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-43.el7_7.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-43.el7_7.3
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-47.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-47.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-48.el7_8.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-48.el7_8.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8.1
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Removing: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686 (installed)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Updated By: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7_9.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7_9.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-18.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-18.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-20.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-20.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-20.el7_1.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-20.el7_1.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7_2.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_2.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7_3.2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_3.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-28.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-28.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-28.el7_4.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-28.el7_4.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-32.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-32.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-33.el7_5.2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-33.el7_5.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-37.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-37.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-38.el7_6.2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-38.el7_6.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-43.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-43.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-43.el7_7.3.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-43.el7_7.3
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-47.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-47.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-48.el7_8.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-48.el7_8.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8.1
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.35-3.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.37-1.el7_0.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-1.el7_0.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-2.el7_0.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.41-2.el7_0.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-1.el7_1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.47-1.el7_2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.50-1.el7_2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.el7_5.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.64-1.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.65-1.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.68-1.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Removing: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686 (installed)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Updated By: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7_9.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7_9.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-18.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-18.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-20.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-20.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-20.el7_1.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-20.el7_1.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7_2.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_2.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7_3.2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_3.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-28.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-28.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-28.el7_4.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-28.el7_4.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-32.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-32.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-33.el7_5.2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-33.el7_5.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-37.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-37.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-38.el7_6.2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-38.el7_6.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-43.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-43.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-43.el7_7.3.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-43.el7_7.3
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-47.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-47.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-48.el7_8.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-48.el7_8.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8.1
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-perl-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64 (@repo/$releasever)
           Requires: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Removing: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686 (installed)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Updated By: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-49.el7_9.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7_9.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-18.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-18.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-20.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-20.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-20.el7_1.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-20.el7_1.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7_2.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_2.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-24.el7_3.2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_3.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-28.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-28.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-28.el7_4.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-28.el7_4.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-32.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-32.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-33.el7_5.2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-33.el7_5.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-37.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-37.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-38.el7_6.2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-38.el7_6.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-43.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-43.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-43.el7_7.3.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-43.el7_7.3
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-47.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-47.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-48.el7_8.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8
           Available: 1:net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-48.el7_8.1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8.1
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.35-3.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.37-1.el7_0.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-1.el7_0.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.40-2.el7_0.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.41-2.el7_0.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-1.el7_1.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.44-2.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.47-1.el7_2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.50-1.el7_2.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.60-1.el7_5.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.64-1.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.65-1.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.68-1.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-perl-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64 (@repo/$releasever)
           Requires: net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Removing: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64 (installed)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-49.el7
           Updated By: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-49.el7_9.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-49.el7_9.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-18.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-18.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-20.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-20.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-20.el7_1.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-20.el7_1.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-24.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7_2.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_2.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7_3.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-24.el7_3.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-28.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-28.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-28.el7_4.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-28.el7_4.1
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-32.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-32.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-33.el7_5.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-33.el7_5.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-37.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-37.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-38.el7_6.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-38.el7_6.2
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-43.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-43.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-43.el7_7.3.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-43.el7_7.3
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-47.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-47.el7
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-48.el7_8.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8
           Available: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-48.el7_8.1.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
               net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-48.el7_8.1
**********************************************************************
yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
**********************************************************************

--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7 will be erased
---> Package net-snmp.x86_64 1:5.7.2-49.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-perl-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
---> Package net-snmp-agent-libs.i686 1:5.7.2-49.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18 for package: 1:net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
Package 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.68-1.el7.i686 is obsoleted by MariaDB-compat-10.3.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18) for package: 1:net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
Package 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.68-1.el7.i686 is obsoleted by MariaDB-compat-10.3.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64 which is already installed
---> Package net-snmp-devel.i686 1:5.7.2-49.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
---> Package net-snmp-libs.i686 1:5.7.2-49.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-perl-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
---> Package net-snmp-libs.x86_64 1:5.7.2-49.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-perl-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
--> Processing Dependency: net-snmp-libs = 1:5.7.2-49.el7 for package: 1:net-snmp-agent-libs-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 21 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
centreon-plugin-Operatingsystems-Linux-Local-20210622-151444.el7.centos.noarch has missing requires of quota
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of krb5-libs(x86-32) = ('0', '1.15.1', '50.el7')
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libcom_err.so.2
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libgssapi_krb5.so.2
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libgssapi_krb5.so.2(gssapi_krb5_2_MIT)
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libgssrpc.so.4
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libk5crypto.so.3
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libkadm5(x86-32) = ('0', '1.15.1', '50.el7')
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libkdb5.so.8
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libkeyutils.so.1
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libkrad.so.0
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libkrb5.so.3
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libkrb5.so.3(krb5_3_MIT)
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libkrb5support.so.0
krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.i686 has missing requires of libselinux.so.1
1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.i686 has missing requires of libcom_err.so.2
1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.i686 has missing requires of libgssapi_krb5.so.2
1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.i686 has missing requires of libk5crypto.so.3
1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.i686 has missing requires of libk5crypto.so.3(k5crypto_3_MIT)
1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.i686 has missing requires of libkrb5.so.3
1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.i686 has missing requires of libkrb5.so.3(krb5_3_MIT)```
````

Comment: You have a version of `net-smp` intalled on the system that is later than what is available in the repos and is required by another package that is to be updated. You or another user either downloaded an rpm of the package and installed it or added an unsupported repo to the system and installed it from there. It is for this reason that isn't advisable to do either of those things. All you can do is to either find the package that depends on it and exclude it from updates or remove the current version of `net-smp` and continue. That may or may not be possible depending on the system itself.

Comment: @keca13 please put the complete output of `yum` command (pastebin, if it's too large for here)

Comment: I re-edit and paste from --> Finished Dependency Resolution , updated package is to much to paste all.

Comment: rpm -qa |grep net-snmp-devel-5.7.2
net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.x86_64

Comment: yum update net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is registered with an entitlement server, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.

No Match for argument: net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686
No package net-snmp-devel-5.7.2-49.el7.i686 available.
No packages marked for update